# .NET 6 C# Getting timeout attempting to connect to Snowflake database

Tags: c#, connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, .net-6.0, snowflake-connector

Every time I try to connect to a snowflake database in .NET 6 using the `Snowflake.Data` NuGet package, I get a timeout after 120 seconds. I've tried it with all correct credentials in the connection string, as well as all incorrect credentials. No matter what the response is the same:

```
[2022-06-26T21:05:06.742Z] Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException (0x80004005): Error: Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect SqlState: 08006, VendorCode: 270001, QueryId:
[2022-06-26T21:05:06.743Z]  ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error: Request reach its timeout. SqlState: , VendorCode: 270007, QueryId: )
```

My code setup looks like this to connect:

```
using (var conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = @"
                    ACCOUNT=<account>;
                    USER=<user>;
                    PASSWORD=<password>;
                    ROLE=<role>;
                    DB=<db>;
                    WAREHOUSE=<warehouse>";

                _log.Information("Attempting connection to Snowflake...");
                await conn.OpenAsync();
...
```

Every time after attempting to open the connection it hangs for 120 seconds then produces the above error. I've tried async and non-async as well as a bunch of different connection string properties. I also verified I was able to establish an outbound connection to another database with a regular `SqlConnection` and that worked with no issues. Not sure what could be going wrong.

Also ran the Snowcd connection diagnostic tool as descripted in the docs, results were all passing:
[image: snowcd diagnostic results]

Comment: Is it possible that you are not using the correct account information?  That is typically what I've seen.  Also, can you make a connection from the same machine using a different connector?  Perhaps, this is a networking issue?

Comment: I've verified the account information was working in another project. Like I said in the post, I've also attempted to put in intentionally incorrect information to see if it gives me a credentials error, but I still get the exact same timeout, which is weird. I'm able to connect to an Azure database within the exact same project, so I doubt networking issues too :\

Comment: Does the account information include the region identifier or has it been omitted?

Comment: Can you leave the VendorCode visible?  It would allow us to figure out what error you're getting. Do you have a proxy in between by any chance?

Comment: Have you tried to verify connectivity to Snowflake using SnowCD (Connectivity Diagnostic Tool) https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I updated my question in regards to your suggestions. Only specifying the host (which shouldn't be required according to the docs?) fixed it for me, as specified in the answer I posted below. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much trial and error, adding the specific `HOST` value to the connection string was what fixed it for me. Specifying the full account with region for the `ACCOUNT` value did not work. Only when done under `HOST`. Although the GitHub documentation states that `HOST` is not required, specifying it with the region is the only thing that prevented timeouts on my end.